# How to make splash screen image visible in navigation bar also?

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, material-design, splash-screen

I have an image which I want to place in splash screen in such a way that it is visible in navigation bar also at the top. Normally the image is visible in full activity except the navigation bar. But I want it to start from navigation bar also as in swiggy app splash screen.

Below is the related image:

[image: splash screen in which image is visible in navigation bar also]

Answer (score 0):

Try this add to the manifest the theme of the first activity to exclude the action bar, and maybe even the notification bar?

**Method 1**

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/lojacidadao"
android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name="com.example.basicmaponline.Intro"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Method 2**

Another way is, do this through code in the activity. In your activity do the following before calling setContentView() function

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

the reason you have the action bar is because you have set the default theme to have it, in the application tag, so it's not an activity before yours, it's really your own splash activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your splash screen activity theme in `styles.xml` add

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you set activity theme none(default in manifest) and set image fill_parent, the screen is displayed like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setFullScreenView();
    }

    public void setFullScreenView() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
            v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash); // set your view here
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    startActivity(MainActivity.class);

            }
        }, 2500);
    }

    /**
     * @param cls ClassName.class to start new Activity
     */
    private void startActivity(Class<?> cls) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, cls);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
}
```